# How to display the installed applications in alphabetical order of application name using winget?

Tags: windows, terminal, winget

Using winget,
[image: Listing applications using winget]

`winget list` command displays the list of the applications currently installed in my computer, but it doesn't display the applications in alphabetical order of application name just like in the control panel,

[image: Program and Features - Control Panel]

Is there a way to display the installed applications in alphabetical order of application name using `winget`?

Note: The two images are from different machines.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no sort on the output of list today. The Issue covering sorting output is https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/1155.

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to see if there was a parameter/option to accompany the winget command, and really wanted to just comment on the answer by Trenly; I had been using a similar piped command (just shorter), so he should still get the credit!

However, apparently, I must have a certain reputation score to even comment on his (or any other) answer... Yet, I can provide an answer without any rating whatsoever; go figure. So, the shorter version, similar to his answer, but without the unnecessary nested piping:

winget list|Sort-Object

Answer (score 1):

As Demetrius mentioned in his comment, there isn't an ability to sort built into the client currently. However, in your screenshot I see you are using PowerShell. You can use PowerShell variables and commands to effectively sort the output. By chaining a few commands together, it is possible to re-create the table. This seemed to work for me -

```
$a=winget list;$a|select -First 3;$a|select -Skip 3|Sort-Object|select -First 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `ConvertFrom-FixedColumnTable` function at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74297741/11289937) to convert the result of `winget list` to a table.

I created a function `winget_list_OrderBy` in order to make it simple:

```
function winget_list_OrderBy {
    <#
    .EXAMPLE
        winget_list_OrderBy
    .EXAMPLE
        winget_list_OrderBy -OrderBy 'Name' -Arguments "--id=Git.Git"
    #>


    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]
        $OrderBy = 'Name', # $OrderBy can be equal to 'Name'/'Id'/'Version'/'Source' (and 'Available' if exist).

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]
        $Arguments = ''
    )
    # Backup the original [Console]::OutputEncoding
    $encoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
    # Make PowerShell interpret winget.exe's output as UTF-8
    [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()

    (winget list $Arguments) -match '^(\p{L}|-)' | # filter out progress-display lines
    ConvertFrom-FixedColumnTable |      # parse output into objects
    Sort-Object $OrderBy |              # sort by the ID property (column)
    Format-Table                        # display the objects in tabular format

    # Restore the original [Console]::OutputEncoding afterwards
    [Console]::OutputEncoding = $encoding

}
```

Usage is simple: `winget_list_OrderBy -OrderBy $OrderBy -Arguments $Arguments` or `winget_list_OrderBy`.

Answer (score 0):

thoughts on this?  It may need a little clean up, but I just converted the results to an object Array.

```
$apps = @("Microsoft Visual Studio Code", "Microsoft Visual Studio Code Insiders", "Visual Studio Community 2022")

$global:foundapps = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
foreach ($app in $apps) {
    $Applist = winget search $app
    $header = $Applist[1]
    $nameposition = $header.indexof('Name')
    $idPosition = $header.indexof('Id')
    $versionPosition = $header.indexof('Version')
    $sourceposition = $header.indexof('Source')
    $name = $header.substring($nameposition, $idPosition).replace(' ', '')
    $id = $header.substring($idPosition, ($versionPosition - $idPosition)).replace(' ', '')
    $iVersiond = $header.substring($versionPosition, ($sourceposition - $versionPosition)).replace(' ', '')
    $source = $header.substring($sourceposition, ($header.length - $sourceposition)).replace(' ', '')
    $appstoadd = $Applist | select-object -skip 3
    foreach ($AppToAdd in $appstoadd) {
        $foundapps.Add([PSCustomObject] @{
                "Name"    = $AppToAdd.substring($nameposition, $idPosition).replace(' ', '')
                "Version" = $AppToAdd.substring($versionPosition, ($sourceposition - $versionPosition)).replace(' ', '')
                "ID"      = $AppToAdd.substring($idPosition, ($versionPosition - $idPosition)).replace(' ', '')
                "Source"  = $AppToAdd.substring($sourceposition, ($header.length - $sourceposition)).replace(' ', '')
            })
    }
}
$foundapps |fl
```